# PayPal - Use REST API and Adaptive Payments together

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I need some features from both APIs but I don't know how to do this.
Chained Payment from Adaptive Payments and Order from REST API.
When somebody click 'Buy Now' button, I need create an order and process it, but there must be two receivers, like in chained payments.
Any ideas?
Need for MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let us define terms. **Adaptive Payments** is PayPal service which enables you to make:

1. Simple payments
2. Parallel payments
3. Chained payments

### Simple payments

You are selling your items, and you are a money receiver (also, someone else can be receiver and you can only host the website, but in most cases you are receiver) then you should implement simple payments:

[image]

### Parallel payments

If user can place an order which can hold different items from different sellers you need Adaptive Payment - Parallel payment as it is described on the following image:

[image]

This diagram shows a payment in which the sender pays multiple receivers in a parallel payment. With parallel payments, the sender can see the transaction to each receiver

### Chained payments

If you are only receiver and then you will distribute money to other receivers that you should implement chained payments:

[image]

So, if you need to implement all 3 options you need to work with Adaptive Payments API.

Comment: I need only Chained payments from Active Paymets API, but I also need create and process order which is possible with REST API. But REST hasn't ability to execuet chained payment. I need one feature from AP API and one from REST API. How I can do this in MVC project?

Comment: You can't. You can use product A or product B. Pick the product that is good enough/closest, perhaps implementing yourself some of the additional logic you need.

Comment: Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: We are glad that we helped :)